# Convert xml to class using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am using LINQ to convert from XML file to a class that I have created. no matter what I am trying I am getting 0 in the count of the list.

```cs
List<UpdateMember> updateMembers = new List<ExeTeam.UpdateMember>();
updateMembers = GetMember(doc);
try
{
  IEnumerable<UpdateMember> member = from r in doc.Descendants("UpdateMember").Descendants("member")
  select new UpdateMember()
  {
    Birthdate = (string)(r.Element("Birthdate")) == string.Empty ? DateTimeParser((DateTime)(r.Element("Birthdate"))) : DateTime.Now,
    Email = (string)r.Element("Email") != null ? (string)r.Element("Email") : "",
    FamilyStatus = (string)r.Element("Familystatus") != null ? (string)r.Element("Familystatus") : "",
    ID = (int)r.Element("IdNumber") != 0 ? (int)r.Element("IdNumber") : 0,
    Phone1 = (int)r.Element("Telephone1") != 0 ? (int)r.Element("Telephone1") : 0,
    Phone2 = (int)r.Element("Telephone2") != 0 ? (int)r.Element("Telephone2") : 0,
    phone3 = (int)r.Element("Telephone3") != 0 ? (int)r.Element("Telephone3") : 0
  };
  return member.ToList();
}
```

The xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
  <UpdateMember xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    <member>
      <Birthdate>25122012</Birthdate>
      <Email>fake@testing.com</Email>
      <Familystatus>single</Familystatus>
      <IdNumber>12345678</IdNumber>
      <Telephone1>123-4567890</Telephone1>
      <Telephone2></Telephone2>
      <Telephone3></Telephone3>
    </member>
  </UpdateMember>
```

In the line `from r in doc.Decendants("")...`
I have tried all kind of variations.
Thank to all

Comment: could you post your XML, too?

Comment: So how does `doc` look like?

Comment: maybe you should use `Member` instead of `member`?

Comment: Why are you writing `x != 0 ? x : 0`?

Comment: I am making sure that if no value in the element then i will insert default value

Comment: @Danny: Checking for `0` and using `0` instead won't do anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is namespaces:

```
<UpdateMember xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
```

That means all your elements are in that namespace, by default. Your queries all try to look for elements which *aren't* in a namespace, e.g.

```
Element("Familystatus")
```

This is very easy to fix in LINQ to XML:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://tempuri.org/";
IEnumerable<UpdateMember> member = from r in doc.Descendants(ns + "UpdateMember")
                                                .Descendants(ns + "member")
// etc
```

Additionally, your attempt to handle missing data won't work and is overly complicated. For example, this:

```
Phone1 = (int)r.Element("Telephone1") != 0 ? (int)r.Element("Telephone1") : 0
```

should be:

```
Phone1 = (int?) r.Element(ns + "Telephone1") ?? 0
```

If you cast to `int`, it won't give a value of `0` if the value is missing - it will throw an exception. Casting to `int?` will give a null value instead.

I would change your whole code to:

```
return doc.Descendants(ns + "UpdateMember").Descendants(ns + "member")
          .Select (r => new UpdateMember
          {
              // Really? This is an odd default.
              Birthdate = (DateTime?) r.Element(ns + "Birthdate") ?? DateTime.Now,
              Email = (string) r.Element(ns + "Email") ?? "",
              FamilyStatus = (string) r.Element(ns + "Familystatus) ?? "",
              ID = (int?) r.Element(ns + "IDNumber") ?? 0,
              Phone1 = (int?) r.Element(ns + "Telephone1") ?? 0,
              Phone2 = (int?) r.Element(ns + "Telephone2") ?? 0,
              Phone3 = (int?) r.Element(ns + "Telephone3") ?? 0)
          })
          .ToList();
```

EDIT: As noted in comments, storing phone numbers as `int` values is a really bad idea. You'd lose any formatting, you'd lose leading zeroes, and I'd expect many full phone numbers to be outside the range of an `int` anyway. I'd keep them as strings.

Comment: Wouldn't the "-" in the phone number cause a cast exception?

Comment: Having problems with the datetime input but i will fix it.Thank you very much

Comment: @Cory: If the phone numbers actually include the dashes, yes. Storing phone numbers in an `int` is definitely not a good idea, but that's somewhat aside from the main issue here. Will note it in an edit though.

Comment: Jon Skeet: I have new xml that also has to be in a class. i am having a bit of trouble , can i send the xml?

Comment: @Danny: No - ask a new question, if you must, following http://tinyurl.com/so-list